# Global upper limit for function of two variables on unbounded domain

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

I have the following function:

$f(a,b) = \frac{(a + a^2 + 6ab + 3b(1 + b))}{(a + a^2 + 2ab + 3b(1 + b))}, a \geq 0, b \geq 0$

I need to show, that the function has an upper limit / converges to a "global maximum" and also, what that upper limit is.

I am pretty certain from Mathematica use, that the upper limit is $\sqrt{3}$ (it could also be higher though, so I cannot presume, it is that value). Now I am looking for a way to prove it.

There is no point, for which the gradient of the function is zero (no point, for which all partial derivatives are 0 at the so time). So, formally, there is no local maximum.

Looking at the edges: The function for $a \rightarrow 0, a \rightarrow \infty$, a \rightarrow 0 and $b \rightarrow \infty$ yields function values of 1 respectively (doesn't matter, what value the other variables take). $a \rightarrow \infty ~ and ~ b \rightarrow \infty$ is indeterminate $(\frac{\infty}{\infty})$.

So, how I am getting to a solution though, is the following:

I set the partial derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial a} = \frac{4b(-a^2 + 3b(1 + b))}{a + a^2 + 2ab + 3b(1 + b))^2} = 0$, which gives me $a = \sqrt{3}\sqrt{b + b^2}$.

Now I take the partial derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial b} = \frac{(4a(a + a^2 - 3b^2))}{(a + a^2 + 2ab + 3b(1 + b))^2}$ and set $a = \sqrt{3}\sqrt{b + b^2}$. For $b \rightarrow \infty$ the value of the partial derivative converges to 0 (so the criterion of the gradient being zero is fulfilled for a local maximum, not checking second derivatives here).

If I set $a = \sqrt{3}\sqrt{b + b^2}$, the initial function becomes: $g(b) = \frac{6b^2 + \sqrt{3}\sqrt{b(1 + b)} + 6b(1 + \sqrt{3}\sqrt{b(1 + b)})}{(6b(1 + b) + \sqrt{3}\sqrt{b(1 + b)}*(1 + 2b)}$.

$g$ has no local maximum (first derivative test). $g(0)=0$, and for $b \rightarrow \infty$ it is $\sqrt 3$, which is my solution.

**Now my question is: Does it work, the way I approached this? And if yes, why is that so? I actually cannot give the reasoning myself, why this actually gives us an upper limit. Basically what I'm doing is: I am looking at all points, for which partial derivates of a is zero (might be a local maximum) and look for the maximum of the function of those points. But why is this an upper limit?**

Note: this also works the other way round (set partial derivative of b to 0, let a go to infinity).

Comment: Your approach does indeed work! :) What you did is to find the [supremum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum) (the formal term for the upper limit you're computing here) over the entire region by finding the supremums on each horizontal (or vertical) slice of the region and then taking the supremum of all those individual supremums. In mathematical notation, this is $\sup_{a \geq 0, b \geq 0} f(a,b) = \sup_{b \geq 0} \bigl(\sup_{a \geq 0} f(a,b) \bigr) = \sup_{a \geq 0} \bigl(\sup_{b \geq 0} f(a,b) \bigr)$.

Comment: Proving that requires a bit of elementary formal analysis. Have you seen any proofs involving $\epsilon$?

Answer (score -1):

Hint: It is $$f(a,b)\le \sqrt{3}$$
You will need to show, that $$\sqrt{3} a^2-a^2+2 \sqrt{3} a b-6 a b+\sqrt{3} a-a+3
   \sqrt{3} b^2-3 b^2+3 \sqrt{3} b-3 b\geq 0$$ for $a,b$ with $a\geq 0,b\geq 0$
Solving $$\frac{\partial f(a,b)}{\partial a}=0$$ and $$\frac{\partial f(a,b)}{\partial b}=0$$ we get 
$$a=-\frac{3}{2},b=\frac{1}{2}$$
It is $$f(a,b)\geq 1$$ and the equal sign holds if $a=1,b=0$

Comment: Hi Mr. Graubner, thanks for your reply. Could you elaborate a little more on that?

Note: I cannot presume, that the upper limit is $\sqrt{3}$, so I need to prove, that there is no "higher upper limit". Or in other words: I am looking for the maximum value, the function can produce.

Comment: Ah sorry, that is obviously shown, if I show your inequality. But couldn't there be a "lower" upper limit then?

Comment: Hi again. Thanks for your reply, but this does not really answer my question. You are solving partial derivatives, but the point $a=-\frac{3}{2}, b = \frac{1}{2}$ is invalid, since it a is negative. $f(a,b) \geq 1$ also does not give us any ground for reasoning the upper limit. For $f(a,b) \leq \sqrt{3}$ I cannot derive a solution. Any more ideas?